# Apache Camel Environment Property file

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am implementing application for job scheduling in apache camel. I am able to read property config data inside camel context xml using spring propertyplaceholder.

How can I pass commandline argument like sit, dev, uat, prod to read config file of specific environment. like app.dev.properties to the camel xml file.

Currently I hardcoded dev in below configuration.

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>Application.dev.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and accessing properties in Apache camel as below

```
    <route id="GET-XML-DATA">
        <from uri="direct:getxmldata"></from>
        <to uri="http://{{appIPAddress}}:{{AppPort}}/getData" />
    </route>
```

I am trying to implement completely xml and less java code

Comment: Post some code first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spring beans profile` where you can define same bean for different environment. This way you would be able to pick environment specific beans